# Graphical environment in gtk+ programming

Tags: gtk, programming, design

I am reading tutorials of GTK+ programming in [gnome developers](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html).
I saw it is somehow different from C# graphical programming in Windows(OS) or even QT creator.

In C# graphical programming, I first design a window (in a designing environment )and then write a program for events of buttons and other kinds of events.
but here in GTK+ there is no graphical environment to design windows and locate buttons and etc.

Is there any way to use such a graphical environment in GTK+? (I don`t want to use QT)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Glade](https://glade.gnome.org/) (package `glade` in Ubuntu) to create user interfaces for GTK+